# how to populate a textfield from an option of a select menu

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i have a form for submitting data, i have two fields, one is a select menu and the other a textfield, 
i am trying to fill my textfield based on an option i choose from the selct menu,

e.g when i choose orange as an option i get circle as the value in my textfield,

this is my selct menu

```
<form action="#">
    <select name="selection">
        <option value="Choose One"selected="selected">Choose One</option>
        <option value="1">asdf1</option>
        <option value="private motor">private motor</option>
        <option value="civian motor">civian motor</option>
    </select><input name="1" type="text">
</form>
```

in my select menu we can see that orange is still the value of my select option for orange

How can i go about this please

Comment: Show what you have done so far, its always better that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is select the item, and get its value on the change event.  This code should do the trick.

```
var sel = document.querySelector("select[name='selection']");
sel.onchange=function()
{
    document.querySelector("input[name='1']").value=sel.value;

};
```